# A constantly scrolling JProgressBar

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jprogressbar, tablecellrenderer

I would like to ask:

1. Is it possible to have a `JProgressBar` that moves incessantly unless stopped explicitly? I know that the most common way to use a `JProgressBar` is to listen for changes and to change the progress by    using the `setValue()`.  If it is , how ?
2. Can a `JProgressBar` be added to the cell of a `JTable`. If so, how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes. I see two solutions here: use a Swing Timer that repeatedly changes the value of the progress bar or use the `setIndeterminate(true)` of the `JProgressBar`.
2. Yes and no. Yes you can use it in a JTable (you need to change the TableCellRenderer). However, if you plan on using the "Indeterminate" progress bar, it won't work because of the JTable rendering mechanism which only "paints" the component but there are no "live" components inside the `JTable`.

Providing more context and what you are actually targetting would probably allow us to give you a more detailed and concise answer.

Comment: It is a video converter so I want to be able to show the user how much progress was made but since I was unable to determine, in figures, how much progress was made, I decided to use the indeterminate progressbar.